# Why can $L$ imply the consistency of ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

In [this note](https://caicedoteaching.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/502-l.pdf), the writer proved the *Theorem 5*.

> Theorem 5 (Godel) $L \models ZFC$.

Then the writer gave a comment on that.

> Note that the argument above **can then be formalized in ZF**, since the proof that choice itself holds in $L$ does not use the axiom of choice in $V$. This establishes Godel’s result that, **if ZF is consistent, then so is ZFC**.

I'm struggling to understand two things here.

1. How can the argument be formalized in ZF? $L$ is a class, but ZF can only talk about set, how can ZF even talk about ZF?
2. How can $L \models ZFC$ justify the consistency of ZFC? Doesn't we need a set model to witness the consistency of a theory? Why does a class model like $L$ work here? Besides, it seems that the writer used the consistency of ZF to get $V$ as a model as ZF, why is it a class model again here?

Comment: The argument is, _if_ there is a (set) model of ZF then $L$ (of that model) is a model of ZFC. Therefore ZFC is consistent if ZF is consistent. And to be clear we say that this argument happens in ZF, but you could do it with much less.

Comment: @ZhenLin Why does this argument happens in ZF? We are considering the relation between the consistency of two theories, isn't the proof in meta-theory level?

Comment: I just said it does not need to happen in ZF. You could carry it out in second-order arithmetic if you like.

Comment: @ZhenLin Why can that happen in ZF? ZF can't even talk about *L*, can it?

Comment: If second order arithmetic can talk about $L$ in a model of ZF then ZF can certainly talk about $L$ in a model of ZF.

Comment: @ZhenLin You can carry this argument in PRA.

Comment: That note looks familiar.

Comment: @ZhenLin I mean how can ZF talk about $L$, since $L$ is a class while ZF can only talk about sets?

Comment: ZF can in fact talk about $L$ and other classes besides, the most obvious one being $V$. But that’s beside the point and you need to stop being distracted by it. I brought up arithmetic specifically so that you would not be confused by the meta-theory and theory being the same.

Comment: @ZhenLin What method does ZF/arithmetic use to talk about that? Seems that not many books or other material talk about this.

Comment: The same way as any other subset of elements of a set. Do you worry about how to talk about the subgroup of elements of order 2 in a group? Or the group of units in a ring? This is the same. You have a model of ZF and you can define $L$ as a certain subset of elements of that model.

Comment: Jn the language of set theory (LOST) used in ZF, a named class is just a convenient abbreviation for a formula. E.g. $x\in On$ ($x$ is an ordinal) abbreviates " $x$ is a transitive set which is well-ordered by $\in$" . It does not say that there exists a set of all ordinals..... We have a $very$ long formula $f$ in one free variable for which we say $x\in L$ when we mean $f(x)$....L does not imply that ZFC is consistent. Godel showed that IF ZFC is consistent then ZFC cannot disprove $\forall x (f(x))$.